# Tika: wrong mime type detected

Tags: apache-tika

This is my straightforward related tika code snippet:

```
public String getMimeType(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {

    TikaConfig tikaConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = tikaConfig.getDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    try {
        MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(bais), metadata);
        String mimetype = mediaType.toString();
        return mimetype;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new DocumentException("Unable to find out MimeType ", e);
    }
}
```

In order to call `getMimeType`:

```
String mimeType = getMimeType(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
```

where `content` is the content of a file (ONLY THE CONTENT).

In order to test this code, I send an straightforward xml formated content:

```
<settings>
  <property>property value</property>
</settings>
```

However, tika returns me that `mimetype` is `text/plain`.

Is there any way to solve that?

Any ideas?

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What happens if you put a proper XML declaration at the start of your file?

Comment: Then it works right...

Comment: Excellent! Just fix your files to be valid xml, then all'll be good :)

Comment: How can i mitigate the missing xml declaration? I have a service that accepts several files from users and cannot just "add" this missing declaration, unless there is a way to inject it before going through detection